# ASP.NET MVC: Pass list of objects from Controller to View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

So this piece of code is my `Controller` class. I am sending a list of books to the `View`

```
public class BooksController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index(int page = 0)
     {
          List<Book> data = BookRepository.GetInstance().getAllBooks();
          return this.View(data);
     }
}
```

So I wrote this on the top refering the model class

`@model BookStore.Models.Book`

When I try to iterate like the below code, it says, it does not contain public instance for `GetEnumerator`, but I returned a list of objects, how do I access each object in the list in the for loop?

```
<ul>
   @foreach(var book in Model)
   {

   }
</ul>
```

Comment: Your model needs to be a list of books, not a single book. Can't iterate over a single item. Try @model List<BookStore.Models.Book>

Comment: Yes! This worked, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is in the following line:

```
@model BookStore.Models.Book
```

You are passing `List<Book>` from controller to view but your view's model type is `Book`. So write the above line as follows:

```
@model List<BookStore.Models.Book>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the list of objects from the controller to view, so you have to use **IEnumerable** or **List** or **IList** keywords in your view's. SO you can use the following ways.

```
@model IEnumerable<BookStore.Models.Book>
```

OR

```
@model IList<BookStore.Models.Book>
```

OR

```
@model List<BookStore.Models.Book>
```

I hope it will work.